# How can I update my div partial?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

my forms goes like this

index.html.erb

```
<div id="comments_p">
  <%= render (:partial => "comment", :collection => tasks.comments) %>
</div>   
<% form_for :comment, :url => comment_task_path(tasks.id), :html => {:remote => true, :class => "comment_form"} do |f| -%>
  <%= f.text_field :remark, :placeholder => "Add Comments", :rows => 2, 
    :style => "width: 834px; height: 40px;"%>
  <%= f.submit "submit"%>
<% end -%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
    this.submit(function() {
      var test = $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
      $(".comment_form")[0].reset();
      alert("Comment Submitted");
      return false
    })
    return this;
  };
</script>
```

application.js

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment_form").submitWithAjax();
})
```

my problem is that how can i update my div. the alert works but i cannot seem to find how to update the div comments_p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the form is submitting to **create** method of **Tasks**  **controller**. As the request is an **js** request in the back-end, so just create a file called **create.js.erb** in **/app/views/tasks/** folder as explained in the [Unobtrusive Javascript Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast) and write the code what ever you want to execute after the sucessful response.

Get the updated **tasks** variable in tasks_controller.rb

```
def create
    #...code for creating the comments for the task
    @tasks = ... #updated record with the latest comments
end
```

then the response code in the **create.js.erb** file shoild be like

```
$("#comments_p").html('<%= render_partial :comment, :collection => @tasks.comments) %>');
```

the **comments_p** div will be updated after the successful completion of the request by the above code.

Comment: Is your issue fixed? or any problem facing?

Comment: its fixed but the problem is that in my rendering the create.js erb